# Linking between jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

Currently I'm working on a project where I've to link between different tabs. I already got the tab section working but not sure how to build a href's to different tabs with anchor points. Could someone help me out.

I also need a link from an external source to be working the same way as the link from one tab to another.

It should anchor to a specific tab and question. I prefer not to use the jquery UI library.

Here is my current project.

http://jsbin.com/kerudolare/edit?html,css,js,output

If you require any additional info let me know.

Kind regards,

Wouter

Comment: have you tried `window.location.redirect="url#tab-name"` ??

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context. I'm sure I haven't tried this yet, but don't know how to do it. :) How do I setup my hrefs to make this work? :)

Comment: your current `url` and only add `#tab-name` thats it.

Comment: Where do I need to integrate the window.location.redirect. And this won't anchor to a specific li item in my tab right? Could you provide me a jsbin, because I'm not a javascript guru. Actually I'm just a designer, trying to solve something haha.

Comment: no need to window.location.redirect. Only do `<a href="www.google.com#tab-name"> `